# TextIOWrapper in Dataflow Pipeline Running Slow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow

I am loading csv files from GCS into BigQuery and triggering the task through Cloud Composer (then doing some other stuff next). The `bq load` command does not parse the file correctly because of various characters present in some of the fields, so I am turning to Dataflow for help parsing and loading. There are 8 files each ~1GB in size. It's 96 columns-worth of data and ~3M records loading directly from GCS to BQ. Most of the fields are STRING with a few NUMERIC and TIMESTAMP types.

My pipeline runs, but incredibly sluggishly. I can read the files successfully into BigQuery, but the pipeline auto-scales to +15 workers at 18 min elapsed time at which point it's only processed ~300k rows. The UI is showing that it's barely pushing 300 elements/s.

I have tried various other solutions posted online, but I need the data to come in un-edited (can't strip out the weird characters) and some other solutions try using `re` to split on the commas, but there are commas everywhere in the STRING fields so that doesn't work for me. (There are also pipes, tabs and any host of potential characters as well so delimiting on something else is not really a helpful option either). The nice part about that solution was the ability to use `apache_beam.Map` to parallelize the operations performed on the records, but it was performed incorrectly giving me bad results with missing or corrupt data on certain records.

The `csv` library is the only thing that consistently parses the file correctly without losing the data. So I am passing the opened GCS file to the `csv.DictReader` in order to write directly to BQ. Whether I am using `self.open_file()` method in the `apache_beam.io.FileBasedSource` class or the `open` method from the `apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsIO` class, I get an `_io.BufferedReader` which is throwing me bytes instead of strings. So I used `io.TextIOWrapper` to get the strings instead of the bytes and that seemed to "work" but ran extremely slow as described above.

I also tried gzipping the csv files initially and reading them in. Instead of using `io.TextIOWrapper` I can use `gzip.open(_io.BufferedReader, 'rt')` and that works like a charm. The pipeline in that case runs consistently and completes in ~20 minutes (still feels like a long time based on what dataflow claims it can do but if that's the best I can get then I can live with that). The `TextIOWrapper` seems to be slowing it down significantly (just my guess) and other solutions with `codecs` didn't seem to work.

Oddly enough the pipeline ran locally with DirectRunner on one of the 8 csv file in less than a minute even with the `TextIOWrapper`. So now I'm just kinda confused.

(I also tried running it in just straight and dirty python writing to `NLD_JSON` then using `bq load` and that worked but took an hour which this process cannot exceed for various reasons.)

Here is my pipeline with the commented parts showing the change necessary for executing on the gzip file:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import

import argparse
from argparse import RawTextHelpFormatter
import logging

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery import WriteToBigQuery
from apache_beam.io.filebasedsource import FileBasedSource

#############################################
# gzipped CSV Reading Class that converts to dictionary
#############################################


class MyCsvFileSource(FileBasedSource):
    def read_records(self, file_pattern, range_tracker):
        import os  # Need to import these inside of class otherwise the Pipeline will not recognize the library
        import csv
        from io import TextIOWrapper  # Comment this line out when reading gzipped csv
        #import gzip  # Uncomment this line when reading gzipped csv
        from apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio import GcsIO
        my_gcs_io = GcsIO(storage_client=os.getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')) 
        # reader = csv.DictReader(gzip.open(my_gcs_io.open(filename=file_pattern, mode='r', mime_type='text/csv'), 'rt'))  # Uncomment this line when reading gzipped csv
        reader = csv.DictReader(TextIOWrapper(my_gcs_io.open(filename=file_pattern, mode='r', mime_type='text/csv')))  # Comment this line out when reading gzipped csv
        for record in reader:
            yield record

#############################################
# Define the Pipeline
#############################################


def run(argv=None):
    """This function defines the argument parser and pipeline arguments used to run the dataflow pipeline"""
    #############################################
    # Argument Parser
    #############################################

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="""
        This is an apache beam pipeline that will read a gzipped csv file and write to bigquery.
        The files can be read from GCS or local and written to bigquery in the same project.
        Required Pipeline Arguments:
        - runner
            To run locally specify the flag `--runner=DirectRunner`
            To run in GCP Dataflow specify the flag `--runner=DataflowRunner`
        - project [required only if accessing GCP, not required for local -> local]
            GCP Project ID where the Dataflow job will execute
            e.g. `--project=my-gcp-project`
        - stagingLocation [can specify local storage as well if running `DirectRunner`]
            Specify a GCS storage location where the Dataflow job can stage the code for workers to execute.
        - temp_location [can specify local storage as well if running `DirectRunner`]
            Specify a GCS storage location where the Dataflow job can stage the data for temporary storage.
        - subnetwork [required for reading from GCP GCS buckets]
            Need to specify a VPC subnetwork for the project using the following format
            `--subnetwork=regions/<REGION_NAME>/subnetworks/<SUB_NETWORK_NAME>`
        """,
        formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument("--input", help='The directory or filename that will be read into the pipeline containting 1 or more gzipped csv files')
    parser.add_argument("--output", help='The `dataset.table` where the records from `--input` will be written to')
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()

    #############################################
    # Dataflow Pipeline
    #############################################

    with beam.Pipeline(argv=pipeline_args) as p:
        (p
         | 'Read Files' >> beam.io.Read(MyCsvFileSource(known_args.input))
         | 'Write to BigQuery' >> WriteToBigQuery(table=known_args.output,
                                                  create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
                                                  write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

I expect this pipeline to run in well under 20 minutes on all 8 regular csv files from GCS to BigQuery and not drop any records in the process.

Would love any help you all can provide.

Comment: Have you already tried putting the CSV file in the same region and/or zone as your Dataflow job and same region as your BigQuery dataset?

Comment: yep, everything is in us-central1. BQ, Dataflow, and Composer.

Answer (score 0):

** Not an answer to your question but an alternative approach **

I understand that you are trying to clean your data while simultaneously loading to BQ. You might want to explore Cloud dataprep (under Big data section in GCP console) which is very intuitive to clean your data and data types for instance (it is built for transforming your data) . Then you can save your cleaned data back to GCS and just launch a load job from BQ UI itself to populate your bigquery table.

Comment: Thanks @Manan kshatriya, but yeah doesn't really address the question. I haven't used Dataprep much beyond initial data profiling. My Dataflow job is running as a task within a Cloud Composer DAG and after it finishes there are other tasks that need to be performed. I am not aware of a way to trigger a Dataprep Flow from a Composer DAG (which I would need to do). I updated the first part of this question indicating that need.